# Own https certbot web server returns me 404 page not found

Tags: ssl, go, https, digital-ocean, certbot

I have pretty simple [go https web server](https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456)

Here is code:

```
package main

import (
    // "fmt"
    // "io"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
    // fmt.Fprintf(w, "This is an example server.\n")
    // io.WriteString(w, "This is an example server.\n")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8085", "fullchain.pem", "privkey.pem", nil)
//    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8085", "certificate_ca.crt", "certificate.csr", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

It listens on port 8085 which is open by farewall.
I use SSL certificate generated by certbot:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com
```

So I built web server using following generated files:

```
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8085", "fullchain.pem", "privkey.pem", nil)
```

Here is port state:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8085
tcp6       0      0 :::8085                 :::*                    LISTEN      23429/hello

$ sudo ufw status | grep 8085
8085/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8085/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

So when I try to from another machine:

```
$ curl -sL https://example.com:8085
404 page not found
```

Web server run on DigitalOcean. Do I need to configure my droplet somehow? Not sure what I missed?
Also I have `certificate.crt, certificate_ca.crt, certificate.csr` files I got from company that sold me domain. Should I use this files someway?
I need this for OAuth redirect URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured a handler for the URL path `/hello`, but you haven't configured a handler for the path `/`. Thus when you try to load that path, you get a 404.

If you tried to load `https://example.com:8085/hello` then you would see the example text.

You could also set up a route for `/`, e.g.:

```
 http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
```

Note that because this matches all possible URLs, you need to check the URL explicitly if you wanted to match only the homepage, for instance:

```
    if req.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, req)
        return
    }
```

You should also consider using a more flexible multiplexer, such as gorilla/mux.

Comment: the answer lay on the surface! Thank you very much!